# Filtering url in _trackEvent to Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Can I accomplish sending a page parameter equal to 'myPage' in

```
_trackEvent(category, action, opt_label, opt_value, opt_noninteraction)
```

the same way as in

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', 'myPage');
```

As we see there is no "page" parameter in `trackEvent`, but there is in `trackPageview`.
This causes my events to be bound to actual page (in reality to index.php), and "pageview" pages to 'myPage'.

If there is no way to sync these pages from JavaScript on my site, is there any way around to do sync in Google's dashboards?

I understand that I can do tricks with .htaccess or web.config (in ISS) to be rid of index.php in ExpressionEngine, but first I need to try to work with Google's framework.